# Mysql don't sort correct value

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have problem with mysql sorting so if some one can help me out to solve this i will be
so happy before i dont understand it at all

[weird info](http://thehunters.se/images/weird.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Since the type of the column is varchar it uses alphabetic ordering which is not like numeric ordering at all. Someone else might be able to tell you how to make it sort as numbers, or you could split the column into two: a number and a suffix (T, W) part. You coulkd even make the suffix an enum in that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
 ORDER BY (best_feralhog + 0.0)
```

It will sort numerically, but it will ignore the suffix letters.

Comment: yeahoo...my headeck is gone thanks all for the help the solution was
ORDER BY sum + 0.0  DESC LIMIT

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider clicking the checkbox to accept the best answer / correct answer that helped you. This allows your question to help other users.

Answer (score 1):

These are sorted.

They are varchar(10). They are sorted using string comparison. The string "1000" is smaller than the string "999" because the first character of the first string, "1", is smaller than the first character of the second string, "9".

If these are numbers, you should store them as such in the database. Consider using the decimal type.

If you really need to store as varchar, you will need to convert (cast) the values to decimal values before sorting.